# how to improve speed while images uploading in jsp?

Tags: javascript, image, file, jsp, parameters

I'm uploading multiple images on server but because of large size it takes large time and some times time out and program fail please help me..

```
File f = new File("webapps/VasundharaProduction/VehicalImg");

if(!f.isDirectory()) 
{
    f.mkdirs();
}

String itemName = item.getName();
if(itemName!="")
{
    imgcnt.add(vish);
    vno=vno.toUpperCase();
    File savedFile1 = new File("webapps\\VasundharaProduction\\VehicalImg\\"+"document"+"_"+vno+"_"+vish+++".jpg");

    //File savedFile1 = new File("D:\\"+"OwnerName_"+"_"+vno+".jpg");
    item.write(savedFile1); 
}
vish++;
```

Comment: Well, either you have to put a thicker cable between your client and server, or, and that's more real, you have to increase the session timeout in your `web.xml`. See https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/java-servlet/0596005725/ch11s03.html for more info.

Comment: Thanx Mr.Chocholacek